# How do I list the symbols in a .so file

Tags: c++, c, gcc, symbols, name-mangling

How do I list the symbols being exported from a .so file?  If possible, I'd also like to know their source (e.g. if they are pulled in from a static library).

I'm using gcc 4.0.2, if that makes a difference.

Comment: The platform makes a difference. Apple provides a GCC 4.0, but its `nm` does not respond to some options, like `-D` and `-g` (IIRC).

Comment: This prints nothing on Mac OS.

Comment: @jww because that's BSD `nm`, not GNU `nm`.

Answer (score 775, accepted):

The standard tool for listing symbols is `nm`, you can use it simply like this:

```
nm -gD yourLib.so
```

If you want to see symbols of a C++ library, add the "-C" option which demangle the symbols (it's far more readable demangled).

```
nm -gDC yourLib.so
```

If your .so file is in elf format, you have two options:

Either `objdump` (`-C` is also useful for demangling C++):

```
$ objdump -TC libz.so

libz.so:     file format elf64-x86-64

DYNAMIC SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000002010 l    d  .init  0000000000000000              .init
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 free
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 __errno_location
0000000000000000  w   D  *UND*  0000000000000000              _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
```

Or use `readelf`:

```
$ readelf -Ws libz.so
Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 112 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND
     1: 0000000000002010     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   10
     2: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND free@GLIBC_2.2.5 (14)
     3: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __errno_location@GLIBC_2.2.5 (14)
     4: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
```

Comment: This doesn't always work with .so files, though, and so you may have to use the "readelf" solution mentioned in another answer.

Comment: Great answer - but I don't get the function signatures from nm, objdump or readelf. Do you know how I can get the function signature (parameters) as well?

Comment: Note that OS X versions of nm are missing the '-C' option for demangling symbols. c++filt can be used instead. Example script here: http://v8.googlecode.com/svn/branches/bleeding_edge/tools/mac-nm

nm -g /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib | c++filt -p -i

Comment: Note that `readelf -Ws` will show you *all* symbols, and `nm -g` shows only the externally visible symbols. This may be confusing if you are examining multiple symbol files and start interchanging your commands.

Comment: I would also add `objectdump -TC` to the list. In contrary to `readelf -Ws`, it doesn't show the mangled names.

Comment: For those searching for what the numbers in parentheses at the end of each line mean, see [this description](http://www.lightofdawn.org/wiki/wiki.cgi/NewAppsOnOldGlibc).

Comment: @BrooksMoses For `.so` files you may need to add `--dynamic` to `nm` command line.

Comment: Much like `readelf`, `objdump` needs the `-W` flag or it might truncate the symbol but unlike `readelf`, `objdump` can demangle the symbols without an external tool.

Comment: `nm -g mylib.so` gave `nm: mylib.so: no symbols`. For reference, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282616/why-nm-shows-no-symbols-for-lib-i386-linux-gnu-libc-so-6

Comment: This generally *doesn't* work for .so files on Linux -- you need to ad `-D` or `--dynamic`

Answer (score 101):

If your `.so` file is in elf format, you can use readelf program to extract symbol information from the binary.  This command will give you the symbol table:

```
readelf -Ws /usr/lib/libexample.so
```

You only should extract those that are defined in this `.so` file, not in the libraries referenced by it.  Seventh column should contain a number in this case.  You can extract it by using a simple regex:

```
readelf -Ws /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep '^\([[:space:]]\+[^[:space:]]\+\)\{6\}[[:space:]]\+[[:digit:]]\+'
```

or, as proposed by [Caspin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28817/caspin),:

```
readelf -Ws /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | awk '{print $8}';
```

Comment: readelf -Ws /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | awk '{print $8}';  regexes are awesome but sometimes a little awk goes a long way.

Answer (score 57):

```
objdump -TC /usr/lib/libexample.so
```

Answer (score 44):

For shared libraries libNAME.so the -D switch was necessary to see symbols in my Linux

```
nm -D libNAME.so
```

and for static library as reported by others

```
nm -g libNAME.a
```

Answer (score 38):

I kept wondering why *-fvisibility=hidden* and *#pragma GCC visibility* did not seem to have any influence, as all the symbols were always visible with *nm* - until I found this post that pointed me to *readelf* and *objdump*, which made me realize that there seem to actually be **two** symbol tables:

- The one you can list with *nm*
- The one you can list with *readelf* and *objdump*

I think the former contains debugging symbols that can be stripped with *strip* or the -s switch that you can give to the linker or the *install* command. And even if nm does not list anything anymore, your exported symbols are still exported because they are in the ELF "dynamic symbol table", which is the latter.

Comment: Thank you!  This explains why sometimes "nm" doesn't show any symbols for .so files.

Comment: nm -D  - lets you list the dynamic symbol table

Answer (score 31):

For C++ `.so` files, the ultimate `nm` command is `nm --demangle --dynamic --defined-only --extern-only <my.so>`

```
# nm --demangle --dynamic --defined-only --extern-only /usr/lib64/libqpid-proton-cpp.so | grep work | grep add
0000000000049500 T proton::work_queue::add(proton::internal::v03::work)
0000000000049580 T proton::work_queue::add(proton::void_function0&)
000000000002e7b0 W proton::work_queue::impl::add_void(proton::internal::v03::work)
000000000002b1f0 T proton::container::impl::add_work_queue()
000000000002dc50 T proton::container::impl::container_work_queue::add(proton::internal::v03::work)
000000000002db60 T proton::container::impl::connection_work_queue::add(proton::internal::v03::work)
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43257338

Comment: No way to see the symbol version though, isn't it?

Comment: @Treviño `nm` has `--with-symbol-versions` on my system. I tried it with `glibc.so`, but the output was the same with it or without it... more investigation needed. eidt: I forgot to use also `--dynamic`. With that, it works. I get e.g. `iswupper` without and `iswupper@@GLIBC_2.2.5` with, in the output.

Answer (score 18):

For Android `.so` files, the NDK toolchain comes with the required tools mentioned in the other answers: `readelf`, `objdump` and `nm`.

Answer (score 13):

You can use the `nm -g` tool from the binutils toolchain. However, their source is not always readily available. and I'm not actually even sure that this information can always be retrieved. Perhaps `objcopy` reveals further information.

/EDIT: The tool's name is of course `nm`. The flag `-g` is used to show only exported symbols.

Answer (score 12):

Try adding -l to the nm flags in order to get the source of each symbol.  If the library is compiled with debugging info (gcc -g) this should be the source file and line number.  As Konrad said, the object file / static library is probably unknown at this point.

Answer (score 7):

nm -g  list the extern variable, which is not necessary exported symbol.
Any non-static file scope variable(in C) are all extern variable.

nm -D  will list the symbol in the dynamic table, which you can find it's address by dlsym.

nm --version

GNU nm 2.17.50.0.6-12.el5 20061020

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to know if there are symbols *present* you can use

```
objdump -h /path/to/object
```

or to list the debug info

```
objdump -g /path/to/object
```