# How to dump the symbols in a .a file

Tags: c++, macos

Can you please tell me how can I dump all the symbols in a .a file on MacOS X?

I am getting a linking error while compiling my c++ problem on MacOS X. I would like to find out if the sybmols exists on the .a file that I am linking with.

Thank you.

Comment: `nm -gC yourLib.a` (based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34732/how-do-i-list-the-symbols-in-a-so-file)

Comment: @sligocki The -C option doesn't seem to exist on Apple's implementation

Answer (score 64, accepted):

[`man nm`](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/nm.1.html)

> Nm displays the name list (symbol
>   table) of each object file in the
>   argument list.  If an argument is an 
>   archive, a listing for each object
>   file in the archive will be produced. 
>   File can be of the form libx.a(x.o),
>   in which case only symbols from that
>   member of the object file are listed. 
>   ... etc

Comment: A similarly useful program is "strings", which prints everything in a binary that looks like a null terminated string.

Answer (score 16):

`nm -g | c++filt`

Mac `nm` doesn't have the demangle option, so you just run the output through `c++filt` (a demangler) afterwards.