# Link C against object from LLVM

Tags: c, llvm, static-linking

I've been playing with LLVM more and ran into a wall trying to do this:

Assuming I have the bitcode of a project (`input.bc`), I can compile that to an object file (`input.o`) using `llc`.

Now if I write a separate file (`funcdefs.c`) that uses some symbol definitions which are in `input.o`, is it possible to compile `funcdefs.c` to its own IR representation using `input.o` as an include?

I've tried `clang -c -emit-llvm input.o funcdefs.c` but I don't see anything that looks like it's finding the missing symbol/global definitions.

Thank you for any guidance!

Comment: Can you provide a source for your funcdefs or reproducable example?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an object file for ***funcdefs.c*** first and then link it with ***input.o***.

```
clang -c funcdefs.c -o funcdefs.o
clang funcdefs.o input.o
```

You can club those into

```
clang funcdefs.c input.o
```

Answer (score 0):

To use functions from `input.o` file you need to create `input.h` file with definition of functions in it. To create such file see [How to call the functions in another compiled *.o object files in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33013044/how-to-call-the-functions-in-another-compiled-o-object-files-in-c) and [How do I find out what all symbols are exported from a shared object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237575/how-do-i-find-out-what-all-symbols-are-exported-from-a-shared-object)