CMake external project as shared library
I'm trying to port a project bash based build system to CMake. I need to fetch FFMpeg, compile it as a shared library and link it to an app.
Here is a minimal reproduction of my setup.
I fetch ffmpeg from github, and build it as an external project.
I have an app.cpp entry point that only contains a call to av_strcasecmp from ffmpeg libavutil to ensure the link is correctly executed at the end of the build.
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)

project(some_project)

include(ExternalProject)

ExternalProject_Add(ffmpeg_build
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg.git
  GIT_TAG b08d7969c550a804a59511c7b83f2dd8cc0499b8
  STEP_TARGETS install
  CONFIGURE_COMMAND
    <SOURCE_DIR>/configure
      --enable-shared
      --disable-static
      --disable-programs
      --disable-doc
      --prefix=<INSTALL_DIR>
)
ExternalProject_Get_Property(ffmpeg_build INSTALL_DIR)

add_library(ffmpeg INTERFACE)
add_dependencies(ffmpeg ffmpeg_build-install)

target_link_libraries(ffmpeg
  INTERFACE ${INSTALL_DIR}/lib/libavutil.so
)
target_include_directories(ffmpeg
  INTERFACE ${INSTALL_DIR}/include
)

add_executable(app app.cpp)
target_link_libraries(app ffmpeg)

FFMpeg seems to be built as expected, all includes and lib files are put in the expected directory.
I have an error on the link stage of the build (indented for better reading):
[100%] Linking CXX executable app
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/app.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/.../build'
[100%] Linking CXX executable app
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/app.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/.../build'
/usr/bin/c++ CMakeFiles/app.dir/app.cpp.o
    -o app
    -Wl,-rpath,/home/.../build/ffmpeg_build-prefix/lib
    ffmpeg_build-prefix/lib/libavutil.so
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/app.dir/app.cpp.o: in function `main':
app.cpp:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `av_strcasecmp(char const*, char const*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Any hint on this ?
Edit:
I've check the built shared lib have the av_strcasecmp function defined:
$ nm -D build/ffmpeg_build-prefix/lib/libavutil.so | grep v_strcasecmp
0000000000023650 T av_strcasecmp@@LIBAVUTIL_59


The first debug step would be to check whether created libavutil.so actually contains the required symbol: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237575/how-do-i-find-out-what-all-symbols-are-exported-from-a-shared-object

Thanks. I think I have the correct symbol in libavutil.so. I've edited the original post to explain this.

Oh, well, libavutil is a C library, which defines C symbols (and av_strcasecmp@@LIBAVUTIL_59 is just an example of a C symbol: it doesn't encode parameters for a function). You use that library in C++ code and forgot to add extern "C" around inclusion of its header.
