# Undefined symbol when trying to load a library with dlopen

Tags: c++, compilation, linker, shared-libraries, dlopen

I'm trying to load a shared library (plugin) I was provided (closed source) with dlopen under a Linux ARM platform. I'm trying to load this way:

```
void* handle = dlopen(<library_path>/<library_name>, RTLD_NOW);
```

The result is a failure with this message:

```
Failed to load <library_path>/<library_name>: undefined symbol: <symbol_name>.
```

I tried to look inside the library with nm, but it seems the lib was stripped, no symbol could be found. I also tried using readelf -s, and, in fact, I got this result:

```
12663: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND <symbol_name>
```

By reading around, I get that readelf -s returns all the symbols, including those symbols  defined in libraries referenced by it.

The answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34732/how-do-i-list-the-symbols-in-a-so-file) question are not completely clear to me: is this a symbol which is supposed to be in the library and which is not there because it was compiled the wrong way or is this a symbol I'm supposed find somewhere else? The output of readelf -d seems to suggest I'm providing all the needed shared libraries. May this error be related to a mistake in the way I'm compiling my executable or is this something not related to the loader?

Also, I read about the meaning of each column, but those values are quite strange. How do you interpret that symbol description? Why is address 0? Why is type NOTYPE?

Comment: Use `nm -D` instead of just `nm`.

Comment: Are you specifically supposed to use `RTLD_NOW`? Otherwise, you may just need to switch to `RTLD_LAZY`.

Comment: @n.m.: Arg! I really didn't know that. The symbol is listed as: U <symbol_name>.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: well, I don't know for certain, but I think it is far better to understand why this is happening and good to notice. The point is also learning anyway.

Comment: What does `file <name of so file>` return?  If I run it against /lib/libm-2.11.1.so I get "ELF 32-bit LSB ..., stripped" and running `nm /lib/libm-2.11.1.so` I get "no symbols".  But doing what @n.m. says, I get a list of functions.  They have be be visible otherwise how would any program work.

Comment: Compare the output of `file <name>` to `file /lib/libm-2.11.1.so` (or whatever version of libm you have) just so you have a reference.

Comment: Yes, file <name of so file> returns stripped. Another question is: why is strip not removing symbols? But maybe this is quite a different question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

undefined symbol: X means always that X should be exported from one of loaded libraries, but it's not. You should find out in which library requested symbol is and link to it.

You should know that this message is always result of problem with library, it's not fault. Library should know how to get all it's symbols. If it doesn't you can link your executable to required library so when you load your plugin, requested symbol is already known.

This error might have more complex reason. In case when both plugin and main app are linking to library, then attempts to link it might end with undefined symbols anyway. This might happen if main app and plugin are using different version of library (namely plugin uses newer one). Then at the point of loading plugin older version is already loaded, so loader assumes everything is ok, but newer version might contain new symbols. If plugin uses them, you will get undefined symbol errors.

Comment: I was unable to load library because of Version Mismatch..thanks +1

Answer (score 5):

This problem appears also if the order of the static libraries in the linking command is wrong for the app. The Unix ld linker requires that the library which implements a function is specified after the library which refers the function.

I got this trouble when I was trying to build libtesseract shared library taking libz library from a custom location (not a standard libz from the host, but manually built from source as well). I have put an example below:

Wrong linking order (-lz before -llept):

```
$ g++  -fPIC -DPIC -shared -nostdlib /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtbeginS.o  -Wl,--whole-archive ....(some libs) -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -L/home/build/jenkins/workspace/tesseract/zlib/bin/lib -L/home/build/jenkins/workspace/tesseract/leptonica/bin/lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lz -llept -lstdc++ -lm -lc -lgcc_s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtendS.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o  -g -O2   -Wl,-soname -Wl,libtesseract.so.4 -o .libs/libtesseract.so.4.0.1
```

Check with "nm -D":

```
$ nm -D .libs/libtesseract.so.4.0.1 | grep deflateInit
                 U deflateInit_
```

Check with "dlopen":

```
Cannot load ./tesseract/src/api/.libs/libtesseract.so.4.0.1 (./tesseract/src/api/.libs/libtesseract.so.4.0.1: undefined symbol: deflateInit_)
```

It happens because the linker is processing in the loop all static libraries passed in the command line and **skipping those which are not used by any of the preceeding ones**. Since on the moment of checking of libz.a the linker sees that all of already checked libraries do not use any function from libz.a the linker just "forgets" libz.a.

Proper linking order (-lz after -llept):

```
$ g++  -fPIC -DPIC -shared -nostdlib /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtbeginS.o  -Wl,--whole-archive ....(some libs) -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -L/home/build/jenkins/workspace/tesseract/zlib/bin/lib -L/home/build/jenkins/workspace/tesseract/leptonica/bin/lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu  -llept -lz -lstdc++ -lm -lc -lgcc_s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtendS.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o  -g -O2   -Wl,-soname -Wl,libtesseract.so.4 -o .libs/libtesseract.so.4.0.1
```

Check with "nm -D":

```
$ nm -D .libs/libtesseract.so.4.0.1 | grep deflateInit
000000000041fb5b T deflateInit_
000000000041fba3 T deflateInit2_
```

"dlopen" did not show this error this time.