# including header files in C and compile

Tags: c, netbeans, include, shared-libraries, snort

I am working with an open source project called [snort](http://www.snort.org) , which is written in C, under Linux. I opened project in netbeans correctly and now I am going to do some changes in this source code. The src folder of program contains several folders and also each folder has some folders. I heard that netbeans is able to generate make files. I am doing some changes in src files in folder XFolder and want to use a library function in another folder in my project (YFolder). I included .h file and used the function correctly.

```
#include"../YFolder/lib.h"
```

Now when I can compile the program, It is Ok, but when I use dynamic libraries ".so (shared object files)" that created in make process; and run program, I see an error that means the function I used from other folder not defined and see this error; (sfxhash_new is the name of external function that I called).

> libsf_sip_preproc.so: undefined symbol: sfxhash_new

I also edited Makefile.am and added the sources of that package (`../YFolder/lib.c and lib.h`); But not effective. Can anyone help me please?

EDIT:

I am in folder src/dynamic-preprocessor/sip
I want to use a function in file: src/sfutil/sfxHash.c
the function name is sfxhash_new(... ... ...)
I included sfxHash.h correctly.
I did some changes In my Makefile.am but the main makefile is this.

My Makefile.am file:

```
## $Id
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS=foreign no-dependencies

INCLUDES = -I../include -I${srcdir}/../libs -I$(srcdir)/includes

libdir = ${exec_prefix}/lib/snort_dynamicpreprocessor

lib_LTLIBRARIES = libsf_sip_preproc.la

libsf_sip_preproc_la_LDFLAGS = -shared -export-dynamic -module @XCCFLAGS@
if SO_WITH_STATIC_LIB
libsf_sip_preproc_la_LIBADD = ../libsf_dynamic_preproc.la
else
nodist_libsf_sip_preproc_la_SOURCES = \
../include/sf_dynamic_preproc_lib.c \
../include/sf_ip.c \

endif

libsf_sip_preproc_la_SOURCES = \
spp_sip.c \
spp_sip.h \
sip_config.c \
sip_config.h \
sip_parser.c \
sip_parser.h \
sip_dialog.c \
sip_dialog.h \
sip_roptions.c \
sip_roptions.h \
sip_utils.c \
sip_utils.h \
sip_debug.h \
../include/sfxhash.c \   -----------------> I have copied src files in this dictionary
../include/sfxhash.h     ------------------>

EXTRA_DIST = \
sf_sip.dsp

all-local: $(LTLIBRARIES)
    $(MAKE) DESTDIR=`pwd`/../build install-libLTLIBRARIES
```

Comment: You have to put the '-lnet -lpcre' etc. flags to the very end of LDFLAGS, did you do it?

Comment: This might help too [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480764/linux-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-s)

Comment: Also note that 'undefined symbol' errors have nothing to do with correct or incorrect header file inclusion; they're linker errors and show that some libraries are missing.

Comment: @H2CO3 there is (-shared -export-dynamic -module @XCCFLAGS@
if SO_WITH_STATIC_LIB) flags after LDFLAGS. I added this in Makefile.am and configured my project again; then I make that package.. But steel I see that error!

Comment: Then show us your exact directory layout and the whole makefile.

Comment: How can I link external library function correctly in this part of project? make file contains (AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS=foreign no-dependencies) in first line

Comment: @H2CO3: I added my make file If another this is necessary please tell me.

Comment: @xebo: Thank you Mr. But the .so file is correctly located and I specified it for my program. I also did some changes successfully in my src files; but when I want to use another part of my program, I have this problem.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34732/how-do-i-list-the-symbols-in-a-so-file) is an earlier post that helps you how to examine the .so file, what symbols it exports.

Comment: @xebo: Thank you; Your prior link was useful about Linker and Libraries to me.

Comment: @sajad: No problem. :) Keep up. :)

Answer (score 2):

After making changes in `Makefile.am` file, the changes are not reflected immediately (i.e. if you run `configure` & `make` you will not see the changes). You should generate/update the corresponding `Makefile.in` file first. For that you need to run `automake` command in the topmost directory of the source tree (where `configure.in` or `configure.ac` resides). To make sure that your `Makefile.am` changes to include new sources will successfully be reflected in the build, check that `libsf_sip_preproc_la_SOURCES` is same set of files in `Makefile.am` as well as `Makefile.in`. Now, run `configure` and `make` commands.
Note that adding a file from one place to another in the source tree may bring in its own set of dependencies i.e. `sfxhash` source files may include files & link to libraries which are not present as part of `Makefile.am` in question, in which case you may have to update `INCLUDES` to include the directory needed by the source and/or add new libraries in `libsf_sip_preproc_la_LIBADD`. Avoid mixing `.la` & `.a` files in `libsf_sip_preproc_la_LIBADD`.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

As you have written:

```
libsf_sip_preproc_la_LDFLAGS = -shared -export-dynamic -module @XCCFLAGS@
if SO_WITH_STATIC_LIB
libsf_sip_preproc_la_LIBADD = ../libsf_dynamic_preproc.la
else
nodist_libsf_sip_preproc_la_SOURCES = \
../include/sf_dynamic_preproc_lib.c \
../include/sf_ip.c \

endif
```

if SO_WITH_STATIC_LIB is true, I think this line:

```
libsf_sip_preproc_la_LIBADD = ../libsf_dynamic_preproc.la
```

should be

```
libsf_sip_preproc_la_LIBADD = ../libsf_dynamic_preproc.a
```

that is my idea, you can try it.

Comment: That is not correct. `.la` file are libtool archive files, these are used by `libtool` to generate both static & dynamic libraries as per need