# How to capture complete 360 sphere photo from android camera?

Tags: android, camera, virtual-reality, 360-virtual-reality

I have a task to capture 360 photos from an android device with image stitching. I have made lots of research for this but didn't get working solution. Note, the task is not just simple 360 panorama, it should be like 360 sphere image. Not an external 360 Camera hardware is allowed. Please help!

Like google street view app...

Comment: Are you trying to get image format that Google Camera uses: https://support.google.com/googlecamera/answer/2840225?hl=en or write your own camera app to do the same as Google Camera?

Comment: Write own camera app which captures 360 photo sphere. save it in jpg or png format.   Then use that image in VR view which play 360 images. This is the concept

Comment: Related: [The algorithm behind Google's PhotoSphere on Android 4.3/4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21682541/295004) and [Photo stitching/panorama API/DLL/Library anyone?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4335689/295004) for looking at PC solutions which you may be able to port or run server side.

Comment: Thank you. But i am not looking for Pc or iOS i am looking for Android related material.

Comment: Dealing with the same problem. Did you any ways to solve this?