# How to get NDK toolchain utilities to list symbols (function names) of NDK-built library on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, android-ndk, shared-libraries, static-libraries, symbols

I have a couple of libraries built by the NDK for which I am trying to view the exported symbols, the available function names to be precise.  One is a .so file and the other a .a file.  I was helped in this question ([How to obtain readelf and objdump binaries for OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33683005/how-to-obtain-readelf-and-objdump-binaries-for-os-x)) to find the utilities that I think I need.  They are specific to the NDK installation. I am on OS X fyi.

In my NDK installation I found nm and objdump in prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/arm-linux-androideabi/bin. Their file type is "Alias".  When I ran `nm -g libMylib.so` nothing happened -- at all. When I ran `objdump -TC libMylib.so` I got: `"objdump: command not found"`. Then I found the arm-linux-androideabi-nm and arm-linux-androideabi-objdump files (file type listed as "Unix Executable File" in Finder) in the prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin dir. The attempt to use *both* of them resulted in "command not found". In all these attempts I placed libMylib.so right in the very folder with the utility I'm trying to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is basically a general issue about how to call binaries in unix; even if you are in the same directory when you run `nm -g libMylib.so`, since `.` normally isn't part of your `$PATH`. To run the right one, do `./nm -g libMylib.so`, or without using `cd` to enter this directory first, just do `path/to/your/NDK/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-nm -g libMylib.so`, or add this directory to your path first:

```
export PATH=path/to/your/NDK/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin:$PATH
arm-linux-androideabi-nm -g libMylib.so
```

(It's preferrable to add this directory to the path instead of the `arm-linux-androideabi` directory, since it is clear which tool you want to invoke when you call when you do `arm-linux-androideabi-nm`, while if you add the other directory and call `nm`, it is up to the order of the directories in `$PATH`.)

See e.g. [Why do you need ./ (dot-slash) before script name to run it in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6331075/3115956) for more explanations about `$PATH`.

Comment: Indeed that was the problem.  nm and objdump both worked on my .so and .a file.