# How to know in which library function is located?

Tags: linux

I have an executable and it calls a function. There are a lot of static and dynamic libraries that are linked with this exe. I need to know which one provides this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a list of shared libraries used by the executable foo like this:

```
ldd -v foo
```

This post:

[How do I list the symbols in a .so file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34732/how-do-i-list-the-symbols-in-a-so-file)

explains how to list symbols (exported functions) in a shared library.

If your library is linked statically, it'll show up in the list of symbols inside the executable itself:

```
nm -C foo
```

The same command will also list the names of all exported symbols (function names) in a static library:

```
nm -C libasan.a
```

You may want to construct a shell script to enumerate your libraries, looking for the specific function that you want inside each one.  For example, to figure out which .a file provides sprintf():

```
for x in *.a; do echo --- ${x} ---; nm -C $x | grep sprintf ; done
```