# Function attribute for dynamically loading functions

Tags: c, dynamic-loading

I want to load a library in runtime using dlopen+dlsym calls. I want to list down the names of the functions which should be loaded using dlsym() and load these functions using a simple 'for' loop. Is there a way to mark functions(maybe using a 'gcc' attribute) to be loaded using 'dl' calls?

Thanks,
Ram.

Comment: Simplest way would be to make one function that fills in the names of the functions, or have them as a variable that you `dlsym`...

Comment: Can you please explain more?

Answer (score 0):

In Unix-like systems there is a command called `nm` which returns the symbols contained in a .so file. Usage is `nm -g filename.so` (you can find more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34732/how-do-i-list-the-symbols-in-a-so-file)).

I guess you can call this command with an `exec` or something like that.

If you can't use exec, you will need to take part of the [source code of the `nm`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/cctools/cctools-758/misc/nm.c) command and use it in your program

Comment: But nm will list all symbols in a given .so. I'm looking for only few functions.

Comment: I guess you have to call `nm` and search the symbols that you want from the output in the C code. Alternatively, since you are executing commands, you can use the `grep` command to parse the output of `nm` in the same `exec` command.

Comment: How can I find only the required functions in the grep output?